# Istio multi-cluster replicated control plane: HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: azure, istio

i followed the documentation for setting up the multi cluster replicated control planes for istio from the document https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/gateways/ and in the final step i am getting 503 error

```
kubectl exec -n foo sleep-f8cbf5b76-fd9kk -c sleep -- curl -I httpbin.bar.global:8000/headers
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
content-length: 91
content-type: text/plain
date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 06:24:00 GMT
server: envoy
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I'm facing the same problem.